# Calculation based on condition in Power-BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a data table that I would like to make a new column based on the calculation with certain conditions.

A sample of my dataset is as below:

[image]

I would like to create a new column "Retailer Margin" with a formula as below:

Retailer Margin = [MRP] - [Retailer Landed Price]

As my data for retailer landed price also have some null (0) values and I want the condition that in such cases calculation should not happen and it should give a "Null" value.

The expected information for new column should be like following:

[image]

Any help on the same will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a [custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column) in Power Query Editor using M, or a [calculated column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns) using DAX. The code for each of these is as follows.

Custom column:

```
Retailer Margin (M) = if ([Retailer Landed Price] <> 0) then [Maximum Retail Price] - [Retailer Landed Price] else null
```

[image]

Computed column:

```
Retailer Margin (DAX) = IF('Table'[Retailer Landed Price] <> 0, 'Table'[Maximum Retail Price] - 'Table'[Retailer Landed Price], BLANK())
```

[image]

In your case it doesn't really matters which one you will choose. The custom column is more logical choice, though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It was of great help.